# Support for an in-remote accelerometer for Google TV

Tags: accelerometer, google-tv

During the I/O 2011 [Building Android Apps for Google TV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxLL-sR6XfM) session (at 37:50 in the YouTube video) Googlers TV guys have said: "Probably not the accelerometer"... **Actually why not?** What about an accelerometer inside the remote-controller (and there is already one if you use your phone/tablet as a remote-controller)? Just imagine playing a 1st person car racing game on your TV using your remote as a driving-wheel (Wiimote style) !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand this will be doable, but it will require two different android apps: One for Google TV and one running on what you are using as a controller (tablet/phone).

The controller app would then use the acceleromter functionality and communicate with Google TV in the same way as the official remote.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an android application I wrote called "iCruZn." It uses the accelerometers in your android phone to control Google Earth on your dekstop. iCruZn transmits the accelerometer data over WiFi to a browser on your desktop running Google Earth. You can use this same mechanism to control an application your write for the Google TV. The only reason iCruZn won't work with Google TV is because the Google Earth Plugin is not compatible with the Google TV Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like new Sony TV has accelerometer in its remote -
http://www.techradar.com/news/television/hands-on-sony-nsz-gs7-review-1063737